# RabbitMQ crash with bump_reduce_memory_use

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using **RabbitMQ 3.7.3** on Erlang 20.2.2 deployed on a docker (image `rabbitmq:3.7-management`).

Memory is setup like this : `Memory high watermark set to 6000 MiB (6291456000 bytes) of 8192 MiB (8589934592 bytes) total`

Here is the crash report that I am getting on automatic restart of RabbitMQ :

> CRASH REPORT Process <0.818.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason:
>   no function clause matching
>   rabbit_priority_queue:handle_info(bump_reduce_memory_use,
>   {state,rabbit_variable_queue,[{10,{vqstate,{0,{[],[]}},{0,{[],[]}},{delta,undefined,0,0,undefined},...}},...],...})
>   line 396 in gen_server2:terminate/3 line 1161

It seems to be due to messages posted to a queue setup like this filled with 500k+ messages :
[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You may have found a bug. Please post this information to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and include the *entire* server and crash log, which will have more information about the crash than what you have posted here. Also, please clarify what you mean by "on automatic restart of RabbitMQ". Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed [this bug](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1535) and opened these pull requests to fix this issue - [`3.7.x` PR](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pull/1536), [`master` PR](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pull/1537). This fix will ship in RabbitMQ `3.7.4`.

In the future, it would be preferable to discuss or report issues on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) as the RabbitMQ core team monitors it daily.

Thanks for reporting this issue and for using RabbitMQ.